# Get an "Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : row names contain missing values" when using R in Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api

I am using [this](https://boraberan.wordpress.com/2014/06/28/dynamic-network-graph-layouts-in-tableau-using-r/) guide to create a nework graph in Tableau 9.0.

To do this, you call R to create calculated fields to plot the coordinates of the graph.

When I load his sample workbook, it works just fine, but when I apply his formulas to my own data (even after structuring it exactly like his data), I get the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : row names contain missing values
```

If I understand correctly that is an error related to the cbind argument in the following snippet:

```
SCRIPT_STR("library(igraph); library(plyr);set.seed(123);
mydf <- data.frame(from=.arg1, to=.arg2, weight=.arg3, Order=.arg4);
mydf <-mydf[(mydf$Order=='1') & (!is.na(mydf$to)),];
mygraph <- graph.data.frame(mydf);
coords <- "+[Layout]+"(mygraph, weights=E(mygraph)$weight);
c<-cbind(coords, data.frame(users=V(mygraph)$name));
c<-cbind(c, betweenness(mygraph));
allusers <- data.frame(users=.arg5);
c<-join(allusers, c, by = 'users');
paste(c[,2],c[,3],c[,4], sep='~')",ATTR([LeadGame]),ATTR([WithGame]),SUM([BoughtTogether]),ATTR([PathOrder]), ATTR([AltGame]))
```

For those not familiart, the SCRIPT_STR in Tableau calls R through Rserve.  The ATTR([LeadGame])... at the very end defines the five args specified in the R code.

Any ideas why this would work perfectly on his data, but produce the above error on mine?  again, the structure is the same, the numbers and names are just different.

Comment: No, it is a list of the different games and their sales- two separate columns combined into a single list.  the 'c' that calls that has calculated x and y for each of the items in the list with no nulls

Comment: The next call, where it cbinds betweenness(mygraph) to c, has values of 0 for each x/y/users row from the original c.  Not nulls, though

Comment: shouldn't this be `coords` not `c`

Answer (score 2):

I would first confirm that you meant `c` and not `coords` in:

```
c<-cbind(c, betweenness(mygraph));
```

If that does not do it note the following

You will get a similar error if there is an NA in the `names` of the value being `cbind`'d:

```
DF <- data.frame(A=1:5, B=rnorm(5))
names(col2) <- c('AA', 'BB', NA, 'DD', 'EE')
cbind(col2, DF)
```

Check the `names()` values of each object being `cbind`ed

Comment: If I check names(coords) I get NULL.  If I just display coords, I get two columns of coordinates with x and y as the column headings....would that be my issue?

Comment: Also, to your first point, the c<-cbind(c,...) works with his sample dataset, so I woulld imagine it should work in mine, right?

Coords was cbind to c in the previous call, so this one just binds the betweenness to c (which already contains coords).